# How to spread light more

Tags: lighting

Which one is better for light bulbs in home to get more from light.

- White board behind bulb?
- White plastic covering the bulb?
- Mirror behind the bulb?
- Any other way?

How to get more from a light source?

Comment: Use clear bulbs instead of frosted.  Also, low voltage with constant color spectrum is generally a better quality.

Answer (score 4):

If you want get more light to specific spot - use "Mirror board behind bulb".

But if you want to feel that room is more brighten, then you have to add more light sources. Feeling of brightness come from various sources: lamps, walls, objects in room. E.g. if there are lot of shadows, room may not look bright. If walls are black/dark grey, it again may not look bright.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question correctly, you are trying to get more general illumination in the space from your bulb or bulbs.  If this is so, consider this.  A bulb has a specific capacity to produce visible light measured in "Lumens" This is the total amount it can produce. It cannot be increased, but can be redirected or reflected. Any type of reflector, mirror, polished metal or white background will reflect some of the light. (angle of incidence equals the angle of reflection) You will not see a huge difference in general illumination from a small source such as a 60 or 100 watt bulb. If the area you are trying to light is too dark with the existing lighting, you will have to add more lights or increase the lumen capacity of the fixture you have by putting in a larger bulb. (higher lumens)

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to focus light into a particular area, you're better off getting a bulb that already does that - there are many different types of spotlights, with different patterns & beams.

If you're just looking to get more light in general, you could probably replace an existing incandescent build with a higher output CFL - a fixture that is rated for 60 watts can easily handle a 26w CFL, which is the equivalent of 100w.

Comment: What about getting 'more' from any existing bulb, to make it more bright

Answer (score 1):

If you want light concentrated on a specific spot, get a special type of light or some [track lighting](http://www.lowes.com/pd_216892-2120-16025_0__?productId=1060483&Ntt=track&pl=1&currentURL=%2Fpl__0__s%3FNtt%3Dtrack).

If you don't want that, then mirrors are the second best, but mirrors can mess with your head, and they will do nothing to make the light less harsh.  A white surface near the bulb, however, will make the light spread out in a much softer manner and will help illuminate the room more evenly.

Another thing that will soften up the light is getting a frosted bulb... or a chandelier that does the same thing on a larger scale, [like this one](http://www.lowes.com/pd_99512-2120-34281_4294796531_4294937087_?productId=1267115&Ns=p_product_prd_lis_ord_nbr|0||p_product_quantity_sold|1&pl=1&currentURL=%2Fpl_Lighting%2BLibbe_4294796531_4294937087_%3FNs%3Dp_product_prd_lis_ord_nbr|0||p_product_quantity_sold|1&facetInfo=Lighting%20Libbe).

Comment: I already mentioned 'spread' in question because i don't want focusing light in room or any other required place

Comment: "Spread" can have different meanings.  Mirrors will reflect light rather than absorbing it like dark-colored surfaces will.  In some sense, that could be described as "spreading" the light, but as it was explained, they won't do much to *SOFTEN* the light.  It sounds like you want to soften the light as well as increase illumination, so a white surface and frosted bulb/chandelier will be what you want.